# Let $\{f_k\}$ be measurable functions such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int |f_k|d\mu<\infty$ Show that $\lim_{k\rightarrow 0}f_k(x)=0$ almost everywhere.

Tags: lebesgue-integral

> Let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions such that 
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int |f_k|d\mu<\infty$$
>   Show that $\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow 0}f_k(x)=0$ almos everywhere.

Since $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int |f_k|d\mu<\infty$ I know that $\int |f_k|d\mu\rightarrow 0$, which means that the functions $f_k$ must be tending to zero almost everywhere, but I can't find a way to prove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by Tonelli, pairing with counting measure and $\mu$, one has
\begin{align*}
\int\sum|f_{k}|<\infty,
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\sum|f_{k}(x)|<\infty,~~~~\text{a.e.}~x,
\end{align*}
can you finish from here?

Comment: Interchanging the sum with the integral is justified by monotone convergence, I presume?

Comment: When everything is positive, the sum and integral can be interchanged. See [Tonelli's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function).

Comment: let me try, I didn't thought of the monotone convergence theorem

Comment: I suppose Tonelli works as well. You just might want to make a note of that in your answer.